# sending message from express to html

Tags: html, node.js, express, mean

I need to send a warning message from express to the browser.
So, I need help to do it. Currently I am working with a MEAN app.
Here, I have to communicate between Express and HTML.

Answer (score 2):

I will give you an example using express and [.ejs](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) as a view engine. It gives more flexibity than plain .html but is still simple (and looks nearly identical).

This way you can setup your routing (the way you redirect users to different sites based on address/path) and at the same time pass data to your views.

router.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('someView', {msg: 'Express'});
});
```

Above will pass a variable called **msg** with value *Express* and render yourView (basically some of your pages).

yourView.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><%= msg %></title> // here is how you can use variable passed from back-end in .ejs templates
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello there</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course you can pass arrays, json, obj etc. to your view.

router2.js

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var obj = {a: 1, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3, e: 5};
var objJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);

res.render('demo', {arr: arr, objJSON: objJSON}); // key: value, so you will refer by key in your view
```

You could also use this values in view's JS scripts.
For example like this

```
// html/ejs markup here
<body>
// bla bla...
<script>
    var tmp = <%= msg %>
    alert(tmp);  
    /* obviously you need some kind of logic when you want
    alert/popup or whatever to happen. At least some simple IF statement.
    */
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However more popular way to display messages to end-users in express is using flash messages. Check out this [link to Connect-Flash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash) middleware. Simple usage is exapl

Comment: will the msg:'Express' look like a popup message.Because I need to dispaly a popup warning to browser from EXPRESS

Comment: Also the example you have given is very easy to understand.thankyou

Comment: The scenario is ,'if the user requests an url that has been already assigned someother user,then on checking the DataBase I need to warn the user to give a different url'.Can you help me for this

Comment: I edited my answer, hopefully that will help you. You should also google it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

See the [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res) of express and read about response. Example:

```
app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res){
  res.send('user ' + req.params.id); // Send to view (html,jade, ejs) somethink message
});
```

> The res object represents the HTTP response that an Express app sends
>   when it gets an HTTP request.

There are more responses methods, as `res.sendFile`, `res.render`, `res.redirect`, etc.

Comment: Actually I need to send a popup warning from EXPRESS to browser.Is that possible?

Comment: The scenario is ,'if the user requests an url that has been already assigned someother user,then on checking the DataBase I need to warn the user to give a different url'.Can you help me for this

Comment: I've tried res.send,res.sendfile...but they dont display popups